# Start Xdebug while performing test with behat and selenium

Tags: selenium, netbeans, xdebug, behat

I configured Behat to work with Selenium Standalone 3.0.1 and Chrome driver, but now, I need to add  breakpoints in my code to debug it, so i need to enable Xdebug.

When my Chrome browser is launched my selenium, I need to add XDEBUG_SESSION_START=1 to the url.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer by myself. You need to add xdebug parameter in senario url :

```
Feature:check account

Scenario: local login
  Given I am on "/login?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug"
  When I fill in "_username" with "testuser"
  And I fill in "_password" with "testuser"
  And I press "Envoyer"
  Then I should be on "/"
  And I should see "Main"
```

In addition, I created a batch file to trigger behat with xdebug

```
SET XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=netbeans-xdebug"
cd C:\netbeanprojetject\myproject
bin\behat.bat
```

Comment: Not the best solution, this would not help if you are using the suite in a CI. A better approach would be to use a debug tag in a BeforeScenario hook to do a post/visit, something similar like here https://github.com/Behat/Behat/issues/703

Comment: I started behat a week ago, so I will figure it out probably later. But thanks

Comment: A note for myself, Attention to have xdebug.remote_autostart =0. Otherwise, curl while gey stuck

Comment: extend the context class and add your own visitpath method with xdebug param